# PHP autloading variable

Tags: php, oop, class, variables

I am not sure if this possible or if this is the right place to post this type of questions but here goes!

Is there any way to autoload a variable with a class of the same name? An example of this:

```
class MyClass
{
    ....
    function display() { echo 'test'; }
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do the following:

```
$MyClass->display();
```

without previously creating an instance of the MyClass class within the $MyClass variable.

As I say I am not sure if this is possible and if this is not the right place for this kind of question I will happily delete my post.

UPDATE
Thanks for all your responses guys, the more I thought about and after reading your comments I realised it just wasn't a good idea and really wouldn't be practical.

Thanks

Comment: why would you want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is make your method `static` and call the method directly on the class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function display() { echo 'test'; }
}

MyClass::display();
```

Apart from that: "Autoloading" variables is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a different approach, and use a static method.

```
class MyClass
{
    ....
    static function display() { echo 'test'; }
}

MyClass::display();
```

You can only do this with functions that act the same no matter what instance of the class.  Your example is a static method, because the function will always return `test`.  If the function had to use instance variables or methods, then you cannot use this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an [static class/function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). You could do `MyClass::display();`.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a static method. You don't need to create an instance of the class to invoke a static method.

```
class foo {
    private static $test;

    public static function test() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

And then invoke it as:

```
foo::test();
```